# Foreach is not working inside Class Method

Tags: php, foreach

I'm leaning about PHP5 Class, Instance I'm new in it. But I'm trying to use `foreach` loop inside `Class Methods` for getting gender of the person but it's only showing right for the first person but not showing right for the second person 3rd and so on.

Here is my code:

```
class Person{
    // atteributes or property of class
    var $first_name;
    var $last_name;
    var $legs = 2;
    var $hand = 2;
    var $gender;
    function say_hello(){
        echo "Hello inside the class from " . get_class($this) . "<br />";
    }
    // full name function
    function full_name(){
        echo $this->first_name ." ". $this->last_name;
    }
    // Gender
    function gender(){
        $names = array("Hamza","Ali","Ibrar","Muqeet","Hassan","Umer","Shaveer");
        foreach($names as $name){
            if($this->first_name == $name){
                echo $this->gender = "Male";
                break;
            }else{
                echo $this->gender = "Female";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

$person = new Person();
$person->first_name = "Hamza";
$person->last_name = "Nisar";
$person->full_name();
echo "<br />";
$person->gender();
echo "<br />";
/*---------------------*/
$person2 = new Person();
$person2->first_name = "Ibrar";
$person2->last_name = "Ahmed";
$person2->full_name();
echo "<br />";
$person2->gender();
echo "<br />";
```

And This is Result:

```
Hamza Nisar
Male
Ibrar Ahmed
Female
```

It has to show Male Also for the second Person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these answers tell you **why** your code was not working. Let's follow the logic of the foreach when first_name = "Ibrar":

```
$names = array("Hamza","Ali","Ibrar","Muqeet","Hassan","Umer","Shaveer");
foreach($names as $name){
    if($this->first_name == $name){
        echo $this->gender = "Male";
        break;
    }else{
        echo $this->gender = "Female";
        break;
    }
}
```

Loop1: the IF statement is false, as "Ibrar" !== "Hamza".  Thus the ELSE is used, which prints female and breaks.

The other answers are good fixes. But let's say you still wanted to use the **foreach** loop. You could do something like this:

```
$this->gender = 'Female';
$names = array("Hamza","Ali","Ibrar","Muqeet","Hassan","Umer","Shaveer");
foreach($names as $name){
    if ($this->first_name === $name) {
        $this-gender = 'Male';
        break;
    }
}

echo $this->gender;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a foreach loop and checking each possibility seems a strange way of achieving this. I would recommend replacing the foreach function with the in_array function which when used in an if statement allows you to do the same thing with less code.

**Example:**

```
<?php 

class Person{
    // atteributes or property of class
    var $first_name;
    var $last_name;
    var $legs = 2;
    var $hand = 2;
    var $gender;
    function say_hello(){
        echo "Hello inside the class from " . get_class($this) . "<br />";
    }
    // full name function
    function full_name(){
        echo $this->first_name ." ". $this->last_name;
    }
    // Gender
    function gender(){
        $names = array("Hamza","Ali","Ibrar","Muqeet","Hassan","Umer","Shaveer");
        if(in_array($this->first_name, $names)){
            echo $this->gender = "Male";
        }
        else {
            echo $this->gender = "Female";
        }
    }
}

$person = new Person();
$person->first_name = "Hamza";
$person->last_name = "Nisar";
$person->full_name();
echo "<br />";
$person->gender();
echo "<br />";
/*---------------------*/
$person2 = new Person();
$person2->first_name = "Ibrar";
$person2->last_name = "Ahmed";
$person2->full_name();
echo "<br />";
$person2->gender();
echo "<br />";

?>
```

Comment: There is no difference, You posted yours when I posted mine so I didn't see it.

Comment: buddies! stop fighting with each other i will vote both of you hehe just tell me that loop is not longer in these kind of work. if i want to do with loop so do you guys have another solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class Person{
    // atteributes or property of class
    var $first_name;
    var $last_name;
    var $legs = 2;
    var $hand = 2;
    var $gender;
    function say_hello(){
        echo "Hello inside the class from " . get_class($this) . "<br />";
    }
    // full name function
    function full_name(){
        echo $this->first_name ." ". $this->last_name;
    }
    // Gender
    function gender($newname){
        $names = array("Hamza","Ali","Ibrar","Muqeet","Hassan","Umer","Shaveer");
        if(in_array($this->first_name, $names)){
            echo $this->gender = "Male";            
        }else{
            echo $this->gender = "Female";          
        }
    }
}

$person = new Person();
$person->first_name = "Hamza";
$person->last_name = "Nisar";
$person->full_name();
echo "<br />";
$person->gender($person->first_name);
echo "<br />";
/*---------------------*/
$person2 = new Person();
$person2->first_name = "Ibrar";
$person2->last_name = "Ahmed";
$person2->full_name();
echo "<br />";
$person2->gender($person2->first_name);
echo "<br />";
?>
```

Comment: So i do not need loop any more are you right for these kind of work.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you need to care about here is the **break** keyword. If you want to get expected result, you need to trace the flow of the code. Here's what it is as per you code says:

**I will start from the section of code where you are doing wrong:**

For `$person` object,
`$person->gender()` will be executed like this:

**Iteration 1:**

`foreach($names as $name)` results `$name = "Hamza"`

`$this->first_name` is `"Hamza"` which is `== $name`

if condition is true here, so "Male" is printed.

`break;` breaks out of the foreach loop.

**No other iterations.**

The output is:

```
Male
```

For `$person2` object,
`$person2->gender()` will be executed like this:

**Iteration 1:**

`foreach($names as $name)` results `$name = "Hamza"`

`$this->first_name` is `"Ibrar"` which is `!= $name`

if condition is not true here i.e. it is false, so "Female" is printed.

`break;` breaks out of the foreach loop.

**No other iterations.**

The output is:

```
Female
```

**Your code isn't saying what you want.**

**It says:**

If the *first item of array* has a name we want, print "Male" otherwise print "Female". We are done and break out of the foreach loop only after checking first item in the array. We don't need to check for other items in the same array.

**So this will be the result:**

For every object of class `Person` you create that doesn't have `$first_name` attribute value as `"Hamza"`, `"Female"` will be printed from the call to member function `gender()`.

**The solution is to write code saying:**

If the condition is `false` you shouldn't break out of the loop as `$this->first_name` must be checked with each of the items in `$names` array. If all the items in the `$names` array return `false`, then the `$gender` attribute value is "Female" that is also printed.

**Solution Code:**
Already mentioned on other answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no foreach requred change yor gender function as below and write echo before function call.

```
function gender(){
    $names = array("Hamza","Ali","Ibrar","Muqeet","Hassan","Umer","Shaveer");
    if(in_array($this->first_name,$names)){
        return $this->gender = "Male";
    }else{
        return $this->gender = "Female";
    }
}
```